# Кто-нибудь может объяснить

Tags: java, переменные, ссылки, объекты

Даны ссылочные переменные hq [0], hq [1], hq [2], hq [3], hq [4] и объекты id = 0, id = 1, id = 2.
Какие ссылочные переменные соответствуют объектам

```
class HeapQuiz {

    int id = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;

        HeapQuiz[] hq = new HeapQuiz[5];

        while (x < 3){
            hq[x] = new HeapQuiz();
            hq[x].id = x;
            x++;
        }

        hq[3] = hq[1];
        hq[4] = hq[1];
        hq[3] = null;
        hq[4] = hq[0];
        hq[0] = hq[3];
        hq[3] = hq[2];
        hq[2] = hq[0];
        System.out.println(hq[x]);
     }

}
```

Comment: нарисуйте пять ячеек и выполните операции присвоения на бумаге. Это нетрудно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null, {id=1}, null, {id=2}, {id=0}